# Java interfaces... Dynamic or static memory?

Tags: java, interface, memory-management

Where do java interfaces reside in memory? Do they reside in the heap or the stack, or maybe global memory? I am thinking the are in the stack since they are created at compile time. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class definitions -- including interfaces and abstract classes -- are held in PermGen space, meaning they are never garbage collected.  The PermGen is, iirc, a part of the heap.

Comment: @Drew Wills: isn't PermGen specific to only Sun VMs?

Comment: @WizardOfOdds that could be -- it's easy (for me) to forget there's any other sort.  PermGen is a part of the generational GC strategy:  it refers to the _permanent_ generation.  Do other JVMs have generational GC?

Comment: @WizardOfOdds won't any answer to this question be JVM-implementation-specific?

Comment: class definition, or class meta data excatly held in PermGen (non-heap space), btw, PermGen is not a part of the heap, see https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jconsole.html

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are technically not "instantiated" in the sense that a regular class instance is created, but class information is stored in the java permgen space. See http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation for more information on the permgen and the difference between a class instance and class information.

Answer (score 0):

Class definitions (including interfaces, etc) are stored on the heap (usually in the Permanent generation because their lifetime is long).  If the `ClassLoader` that created them is garbage collected, they too are then eligible for garbage collection.